# Levenshtein distance function on large dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, nlp

```
Student_ID    0         1          2           3            4           5           6   
131X1319   COMM1370  COMM1307   COMM1315      NaN          NaN         NaN         NaN
13212YX3   COMM2362  COMM4381   MATH1314    COMM1318    COMM4396    POLS2301    COMM4362    
13216131   COMM1318  COMM2362   COMM4381    PSYC3320    COMM4396    COMM4396    SOCI3375
132921W6   CRIJ3380  CRIJ3311     NaN         NaN          NaN         NaN         NaN
132W22YY   COMM2362  COMM1318   COMM4381    COMM3315    COMM4340    COMM3390    COMM1370
132X219Y  COMM2362   COMM1318   HIST1301    COMM4381    POLS2301    CRIJ1301    COMM4397
132Y231B  COMM2371   COMM2371   COMM1307    COMM3340    COMM4310    COMM1373    COMM1373
```

I have this dataframe. I want to apply Levenshtein distance function to this dataset to find  the similarities between each rows of the dataset.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow! this has been asked and answered a number of times, and seeking recommendations for libraries is not [allowed](/help/on-topic) here. check out [thefuzz](https://github.com/seatgeek/thefuzz); especially with the optional `python-Levenshtein` dependency it is quite fast and is the go-to for this operation.

Comment: [rapidfuzz cdist](https://maxbachmann.github.io/RapidFuzz/Usage/process.html#cdist) should be optimized to do just that.

Comment: I am struggling to use thefuzz on a 100 mill dataset - Anything else that's faster?